# A certain partition of 28

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, graph-theory

Given a multiset of positive integers, its P-graph is the loopless graph whose vertex set consists of those integers, any two of which are joined by an edge if they have a common divisor greater than 1, that is, they are not relatively prime.
There are 3718 partitions of 28 of which 291 are partitions into five parts. I have been told that there is just one of these that can be uniquely recovered from its P-graph. Which is it?

Comment: What is the multiset in this case?

Comment: @toliveira: that is what I am looking for.

Comment: Have you tried throwing some (computerized) brute force at the problem, computing the P-graphs of all the partitions and grouping them according to the isomorphism class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a computer search, of the $291$ partitions of $28$ into $5$ parts, the only one whose associated $P$-graph has degree sequence is $3,3,2,1,1$ is
$$3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 10 = 28$$
hence, assuming you know that only one of the partitions is recoverable from its $P$-graph, then that must be the one.

Comment: What is the degree sequence?

Comment: @Chris Custer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)#Degree_sequence

Comment: how did you find the degree sequence?

Comment: @Lifesaving Linen  For the set $\{3,4,5,6,10\}$, we have
$$\text{deg}(10)=3,\;\;\;\text{deg}(6)=3,\;\;\;\text{deg}(4)=2,\;\;\;\text{deg}(3)=1,\;\;\;\text{deg}(5)=1$$
which gives the degree sequence $3,3,2,1,1$.